# MariaDB/MySQL DB tracking another database

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

If I want to have two servers with one active and one hot standby (and each has it's own database on them), how do I get the secondary to track the primary and be quick/easy to deploy if the main server goes down

Right now, I have the two servers that are literally identical. The goal is basically if I connect to 192.168.1.1, it works and if I make a DB change it propagates to the other server (192.168.1.2).

If 192.168.1.1 goes down, then I can simply connect to 192.168.1.2 instead and continue working as if nothing happened. Whether or not the DB changes made on .2 propagate to .1 is irrelevant to me - if it's easier to set them up to circularly replicate vs. master-slave vs. whatever else then I'd rather do that.